# jQuery cycle animation scrollHorz not work properly in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-cycle

in jQuery cycle **scrollHorz** feature animation not properly working when the images forcing to render between anchor tag in **Chrome**. The images render from the right top corner.If I am remove **anchor tag** its working fine in chrome. Its working properly in mozilla.
      [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add image size on stylesheet.

- below is your source

  ```
  .img-responsive, .thumbnail>img, .thumbnail a>img, 
  .carousel-inner>.item>img, .carousel-inner>.item>a>img
         {max-width:100%;height:auto;}
  ```

change source like below

```
 .img-responsive, .thumbnail>img, .thumbnail a>img, 
    .carousel-inner>.item>img, .carousel-inner>.item>a>img
                 {width:780px;height:380px;}
```

- You can refer this [page](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/begin.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. its solved with overwrite `max-width:100%`